# variable for title in R graph

Tags: r

When I try to give the title name as a function argument for Z and for legend, it is not working.. I also tried by just giving z. Please advise..

```
drawGraph <- function(x, y, z) {
    g_range <- range(0,x)
    plot(x, type="o", col="blue", ylim=g_range,axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)
    box()
    axis(1, at=1:19, lab=FALSE)
    text(1:19, par("usr")[3] - 2, srt=45, adj=1.2, labels=y, xpd=T, cex=0.3)
    axis(2, las=1, at=500*0:g_range[2])
    main_title<-as.character(z)
    title(main=main_title, col.main="red", font.main=4)
    title(xlab="Build", col.lab=rgb(0,0.5,0))
    title(ylab="MS", col.lab=rgb(0,0.5,0))
    legend("topright", g_range[2], c("z"), cex=0.8, col=c("blue"), pch=21, lty=1);
}
drawGraph(AET, lab, AveElapsedTime)
```

Comment: How does it not work?  Do you get an error?  No title?  The wrong title?  What's AveElapsedTime?  A string?  Do you want the title to be "AveElapsedTime"?

Comment: I'm getting this error... Error in drawGraph(AET, lab, AveElapsedTime) :
        object "AveElapsedTime" not found
Execution halted
If I give z directly, I'm getting error as like.... Error in title(main = z, col.main = "red", font.main = 4) :
        object "AveElapsedTime" not found
Execution halted

Comment: This function runs without errors for me. Your problem isn't in the function `drawGraph`, it's that `AveElapsedTime` either doesn't exist, or it exists in an environment that's not accessible when you call the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to construct a title outside of the function you could use an `as.expression(z)`. This would let the title be "The average time with ranges: 1 to 8" and the values in the range would be adjusted "on the fly".

```
drawGraph <- function(x, y, z) {
    g_range <- range(0,x)
    plot(x, type="o", col="blue", ylim=g_range,axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)
    box()
    axis(1, at=1:19, lab=FALSE)
    text(1:19, labels=y,par("usr")[3] - 2, srt=45, adj=1.2, xpd=T, cex=0.3)
    axis(2, las=1, at=500*0:g_range[2])
    main_title<-as.expression(z)
    title(main=main_title, col.main="red", font.main=4)
    title(xlab="Build", col.lab=rgb(0,0.5,0))
    title(ylab="MS", col.lab=rgb(0,0.5,0))
    legend("topright", g_range[2], c("z"), cex=0.8, col=c("blue"), pch=21, lty=1);
}
x <- rpois(19, 4)
AveElapsedTime=paste("The average time with ranges:", 
                       round(range(x)[1], 3), 
                        "to" , round(range(x), 3)[1])
lab=1:19
drawGraph(AET, lab, AveElapsedTime)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is AveElapsedTime a variable? If yes,this works:

```
AveElapsedTime <- 50
drawGraph(AET, lab, AveElapsedTime)
```

If it's just text, this works:

```
drawGraph(AET, lab, "AveElapsedTime")
```

Comment: AveElapsedTime is not a variable. It is the example value for Title. I want the title as AveElapsedTime

Comment: Well, your question is called "**variable** for title in R graph".

Answer (score 1):

Quote `AveElapsedTime` so that it's treated as a string and not a variable:

```
drawGraph(AET, lab, "AveElapsedTime")
```